# How customize update interval of aggregator module

Tags: 8, feeds

By default   **update inteval** of RSS aggregator in Core aggregator module start form 15 min, I mean 15 min is minimum value,

[image]

But I need update RSS aggregator shorter than 15 min,and update my feed each 2,5,10 minute too,

How can I set Update interval to what I required?

one solution is using alternative module like [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module but it is not stable yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update interval values for an Aggregator Feed is hardcoded into the [Entity definition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21aggregator%21src%21Entity%21Feed.php/8.2.x) for the refresh field. You'll need to alter the definition to allow different values.

In a custom module, you can evoke [`hook_entity_base_field_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info_alter/8.2.x) to alter the Feed definition to accept shorter intervals:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->get('id') == 'aggregator_feed') {
    $definition = $fields['refresh']->getItemDefinition();
    $intervals = $definition->getSetting('allowed_values');
    $intervals = array(
      120 => '2 min',
      300 => '5 min',
      600 => '10 min',
    ) + $intervals;
    $intervals = $definition->setSetting('allowed_values', $intervals);
    $fields['refresh']->setItemDefinition($definition);
  }
}
```